# servicestack server events with azure RedisServerEvents doesn't work, while default option MemoryServerEvents works

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Question on Servicestack ServerEvents using Azure Redis cache..

Server Code:
I have these lines under Configure method of Global.asax file

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature { 
OnConnect = (res,httpReq) => res.Publish("cmd.onConnect","Message on connect") ,
OnCreated = (res,httpReq) => res.Publish("cmd.onConnect","Message on create"), 
  ...I have custom message for OnSubscription and OnPublish as well
})

**var redisHost = AppSettings.GetString("RedisHost");
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(
    new RedisManagerPool(redisHost));
container.Register<IServerEvents>(c => 
    new RedisServerEvents(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));
container.Resolve<IServerEvents>().Start();**
```

Following is the value format I have in my web.config, for the redis connection

```
add key="RedisHost" value="passKey@Hostname:6380?ssl=true"
```

Client Code:

```
ServerEventConnect connectMsg = null;
var msgs = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
var commands = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
var errors = new List<Exception>();

var client = new ServerEventsClient(baseUri,"home") {
OnConnect = e => connectMsg = e,
OnCommand = commands.Add,
OnMessage = msgs.Add,
OnException = errors.Add,
}.Start();

var connectMsg = client.Connect();

var joinMsg = client.WaitForNextCommand();

connectMsg.Wait();//It gets connnected
joinMsg.Wait(); //When I debug, it is getting lost on this line. I don't get any error message!
```

When I remove Redis registration **marked** above in Global.asax (that is default option MemoryServerEvents) works well. Any suggestion, ideas would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: A few things to try 1) Disable SSL...within Azure under Configuration > Access Ports 2) Try connecting via redis-cli. Using redis-cli you will need to disable SSL. Command would be `redis-cli -h hostName -a passKey -p 6379 ` (or whatever port is assigned)

Comment: Also, to use SSL make sure you're using ServiceStack.Redis v4.0.33+ [note](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Secure-SSL-Redis-connections-to-Azure-Redis)

Comment: hi Paaschpa, thank you for your suggestions.. I have Servicestack.Redis version 4.0.36.0 installed. Also i tried by enabling non-SSL port in Azure and changing the configuration to add key="RedisHost" value="passKey@Hostname:6379", it still doesn't work! I don't get any exception but it goes out of control in  **taskCmd.Wait();** where taskCmd = client.WaitForNextCommand();.. What am I still missing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh God.. Finally I found what the issue is.. It had nothing to do with server events code or its confguration!!! But I have the following line used in my application for a different purpose and which had impact on server events!

```
            // Set the default reuse scope for the container to per request
            container.DefaultReuse = ReuseScope.Request;
```

I guess onConnect is first request and OnJoin or other events are separate requests. As reuse scope was set in my app, it couldn't proceed?! Please share your thoughts if am wrong. Thank you